# Images created with factory faker get deleted when stored in storage/public/images folder

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I'm trying to populate my database with fake images but when faker save it on my images folder after one second it got deleted and on my database field I get 0

I can visit http://lorempixel.com/, also ping it with no problem.

Also tried this: `$faker->image(storage_path('app/public/images'), 800, 800, 'nature', false),`

And changing lorepipsum url like here: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/issues/1715
(http://placekitten.com/ and http://placekitten.com/)

this is my post factory code:

```
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\Post;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'body' => $faker->text(600),
        'slug' => $faker->slug, 
        'metaTitle' => $faker->sentence,
        'metaDescription' => $faker->sentence,
        'user_id' => App\User::all(['id'])->random(),
        'postImage' => $faker->image('public/storage/images',640,480, 'nature', false),
        'visible' => $faker->boolean(85),
        'favorite' => $faker->boolean
    ];
});
```

It should store the image on my storage/public/images folder and give me a random slug.jpeg, but instead is removing it and giving a 0

**EDIT:** Have found if i dd() the faker->image comand it returns false, dunno why...

Comment: What if you try to put the fully qualified path name using `public_path()` helper function? Like so : `'postImage' => $faker->image(public_path('storage/images/'),640,480, 'nature', false),`

Comment: @tcj I can see how it stores the images on the folder but automaticly it gets deleted

Comment: Ok, pretty weird behavior, make sure you don't have some code deleting anything in the folder after the faker is executed.

Comment: No, and also the dd() tells me false, shouldn't be true? since I see how the images gets stored before delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have a folder called `images` under: `storage/app/public` directory.

Have created the symbolic link:

> php artisan storage:link

And finally try with this:

```
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $image = $faker->image();
    $imageFile = new File($image);

    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'body' => $faker->text(600),
        'slug' => $faker->slug, 
        'metaTitle' => $faker->sentence,
        'metaDescription' => $faker->sentence,
        'user_id' => App\User::all(['id'])->random(),
        'image' => Storage::disk('public')->putFile('images', $imageFile),
        'visible' => $faker->boolean(85),
        'favorite' => $faker->boolean
    ];
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on the discussions in chat it seems like it's a cURL issue. Faker is failing on this line (Image.php):

```
$success = curl_exec($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200;
```

And later on, deleting the temp file and returning false as a result.

Comment: Nothing, it still returning 0 on my dataBase postImage field, also I have the storage link correctly

Comment: Updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: Lands an error:    Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined me
thod Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::hashName()

Comment: Add the File namespace at the top

Comment: Ok, now im geting another error: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException  : The file "" does not exist

Comment: It seems `Faker` can't fetch the image. In your question you mentioned you have changed the `$baseUrl`, please make sure you have reverted it to `"https://lorempixel.com/";` in `Image.php`

Comment: Yes I did, also tried two diferent websites, https://picsum.photos/ and http://placekitten.com/ both return false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198233/discussion-between-cristian-and-hatef).

Comment: Got it, finally after some research adding  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); solved the issue, thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Cristian Mine still wasn't working, so I commented out the return line, which allowed me to get an error when viewing the resulting image in a text editor. [It led me here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65426915), so I needed to add: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Chrome/103');`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the photo provider in this case `https://via.placeholder.com` may be blocking the requests and Faker uses this site to generate the images.

You can change this image provider in the `vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/providers\Image.php` file and change the
the `BASE_URL` constant can use another photo provider, eg `https://dummyimage.com` worked fine for me. unfortunately this can only be corrected within the package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.