# curl 1020 error when trying to scrape page using bash script

Tags: bash, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a bash script to access a journal overview [page](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1925128) on SSRN.

I'm trying to use `curl` for this, which works for me on other webpages, but it returns `error code: 1020` for me if I try to run the following codes:

```
curl https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1925128
```

I thought it might have to do with the question mark in the URL, but I got it to work with other pages that contained question marks.

It probably has something to do with what the page's allows to do. However, I can also access the page using R's `rvest` package, so I think it should work in general also using bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the site has blocked access via curl. Change the user agent and it should work fine i.e.

```
curl --user-agent 'Chrome/79' "https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papersstract_id=1925128"
```