# Images from PHPFaker got deleted when stored in storage/app/public/news folder

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I have two tables `news` and `images`. These two tables have one-to-many relationship (one being news). I'm trying to make a factory on images, but right after I migrate with seed, the image saved to news directory but after one second it got deleted, and the path on the database returns `news`. I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589055/images-created-with-factory-faker-get-deleted-when-stored-in-storage-public-imag) but laravel 8.4 (my current laravel project) uses phpfaker, so I guess it's now deprecated.

ImageFactory.php file

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Image;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ImageFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Image::class;

    /**
     * State dari gambarnya, 
     * pilih satu [news, packages, destinations]
     */
    public function news()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'role' => 'news',
            ];
        });
    }
    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'role' => 'packages',
            ];
        });
    }
    public function destinations()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'role' => 'destinations',
            ];
        });
    }

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'path' => 'news' . '/' . $this->faker->image(storage_path('app/public/news'), 2000, 1500, null, false),
        ];
    }
}
```

`storage/app/public` and `storage/app/public/news` has `.gitignore` file. I don't know if this is relevant or not, because my colleagues migrate the seed without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589055/images-created-with-factory-faker-get-deleted-when-stored-in-storage-public-imag#comment101664128_57589731), you just need to go to `Images.php` file on vendor PHPFaker and add these code

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

before `$success = curl_exec($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200;`

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me whre to fine Images.php file? I can't find it in laravel 9